# Yii stat relations multiple column

Tags: activerecord, yii

How to define Yii model relation to retrieve max and min price from single query?

```
SELECT MAX(`price`) as `maxPrice`, MIN(`price`) as `minPrice`
FROM `price` WHERE object_id = :objectId
```

`object_id` - foreign key.

I want to use relation for access min and max prices like this `$object->minPrice`, `$object->maxPrice`.
I looking for stat relation, but that type of relation just allow to retrieve single column.

Comment: please show the schema structure of the related table

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan http://oi61.tinypic.com/2nb7n9s.jpg As you can see, object has many prices

Answer (score 0):

In your model relations function you can do something like this

```
class MyModel extends ActiveRecord {
...

    public function relations(){
        return array(
           ...
           'maxPrice'=>array(self::STAT, 'Price','object_id','select'=>'MAX(price)'),
           'minPrice'=>array(self::STAT, 'Price','object_id','select'=>'MIN(price)'),
        );
    }

}
```

STAT relations does support other statistical expressions in addition to `COUNT(*)` which is the default value, See documentation on [Statistical Queries](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query) and the API reference on [CStatRelation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStatRelation#select-detail)

Comment: actually you're right. Yii docs recommends this way. But doing `$object->maxPrice` and `$object->minPrice` it will generate two separate queries: `SELECT MAX(price) FROM price WHERE object_id = :objectId` and `SELECT MIN(price) FROM price WHERE object_id = :objectId`. I want to do this by one query: `SELECT MAX(price) as maxPrice, MIN(price) as minPrice FROM price WHERE object_id = :objectId`

Comment: then you cannot use stat relation( which will by definition return only scalar output) , you can use createCommand(), or CDbCriteria() if you want to use single query